# How to find when submodule was added to Git

Tags: git, grep, git-submodules, git-log

I want to know the commit when a specific submodule was added, in other words I want to know the commit where .gitmodules file is modified to add the following

```
[submodule "submodule1"]
        path = submodule1
        url = git@bitbucket.org:{user}/submodule1.git
```

I used the following to get the all commits for .gitmodules

```
$ git log -p --follow .gitmodules
commit commit#
Author: auther
Date:   Date

    Description

diff --git a/.gitmodules b/.gitmodules
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..84a18f8
--- /dev/null
+++ b/.gitmodules
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+[submodule "submodule1"]
+       path = submodule1
+       url = git@bitbucket.org:{user}/submodule1.git
```

in this case there is only one commit, but if there is other commits that is adding/deleting other submodules, how can i filter the commits to get the only the commit in which submodule1 was added

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type `$ git log submodule1`, and the oldest commit is what you want.

Or you can add `--reverse` option, and the first commit is what you want.

And notice you **can't** type it as `$ git log submodule1/`, which is likely autocompleted by bash.

And from this question, [Find commit where file was added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533199/git-find-commit-where-file-was-added).

You can type `git log -p --diff-filter=A -- submodule1`

Comment: @MahmoudKhalifa you mean this `git log -p --diff-filter=A -- another_submodule_name` ?

Comment: Thanks it works with the following

    $git log --diff-filter=A --pretty=format:"%h"  --follow submodule_name