# Find the most recently introduced file

Tags: git, command-line

Using Git, how can I find the newest file?

Note this is not the same as the most recently changed file, but the commit that
most recently introduced a file.

Comment: It's not exactly what you are looking for, but ``whatchanged`` will give you files changed in the last commit [source](http://superuser.com/a/117652)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log --diff-filter=A
```

This reveals commits that introduced a file. It can be modified to show only the
last commit that introduced a file

```
git log --diff-filter=A -1
```

or printing the diff of that file

```
git log --diff-filter=A -p
```

or just the stat

```
git log --diff-filter=A --stat
```

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11533199)

Comment: Note that whether a file is "renamed" or "added" is sometimes a question of flags (-M arguments).  @vcsjones: same here. :-)