# GIT: cloning --single-branch yields different result from git clone then checkout branch

Tags: git, branch, clone

I would just like to ask the git gurus here if this is really possible. I cloned a whole repository, then checked out branch A which tracks the repo's origin/A. I tried to build that snapshot and it got me an error. Now I was tasked to try to clone a --single-branch instead, cloning origin/A only since that was their team's workaround.

My question now is that is this possible? I checked both of the branches' (checked out branch vs cloned single branch) latest revision hash and they're the same, but I found out that when I cloned the whole repo, checked out to branch A, there exists a file but this file does not exist when I did the latter (cloned --single-branch).

What are the possible causes of this? I tried looking for the commit where the file was created using [git-log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533199/find-commit-where-file-was-added) but it returns blank. I tried the same command on another file and it works fine.

PS: when I cloned --single-branch A, I'm at branch A and NOT at origin/A.

Comment: Could it be that the file you mention is created by some kind of post-checkout script? (which is not run when using the `git clone --single-branch` command?)
Maybe check if the file you mention is tracked at all by git (using `git ls-tree origin/A -- path-to-folder/containing/file-in-question/` _the trailing slash is important, the result of the command might differ otherwise_)

Comment: Alright will do. Thanks! 'Will keep you posted.

Comment: Okay it seems that the file is indeed not being tracked :(. Thank you!

Comment: I just read my comment again and I explained it a bit confusing.
The `git ls-tree` should be run on the folder **containing** the file in question. For more info [git ls-tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree) documentation.
If the file is indeed not tracked I hope you have a new angle on the problem.

Comment: Hi, yes, it is not tracked, unfortunately. Thanks again! It helped a lot :)

Comment: I think it could be a case of a [post-checkout git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout) triggering in one case but not the other. So could you check the `$GIT_DIR/hooks` directory and report if you can find anything?