# GitHub: How to show commits for all files in folder

Tags: git, github, git-commit

It's not hard to find information on how to see all the files in a particular commit, but I would like the inverse.  IOW, I want a list of all files in a folder and the commit that put them there.  Something like:

```
File1.txt   c7b1fd463f40b39d7f199ee650b58a8ba153b64a
File2.md    d9e3ca571d40b38d7fab90cf50b48a82c1d3a32f
File3.c     3207cab3b49da7be5d9a7ef8594bef1935e15fd1
...
```

Is there some way to do that?

Comment: The commit that put them there, you mean the first commit to reference that particular file in that particular folder? Or the last commit to modify said file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are interested to know what is the most recent commit on your files, this command will give that for a given file: `git log -n 1 -- <your_filename>`.
To produce output like you wish, you can use this snippet:

```
for file in *; do 
  log=$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- $file)
  echo -e "$file\t$log"
done
```

..which is simply looping through the files in current folder and executing the git command, extracting just the SHA.

If you are interested in the *first* commit that put the file there instead of the last commit that touched the file, replace the git command with `git log --diff-filter=A --pretty=format:%H` (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13598028/1092133))

If you are doing this repeatedly you can put the snippet in a shell script and add to your $PATH.

Warning: It might take a while to run if there are too many files. You can change the file pattern to restrict it if possible.

Comment: Nice!  I assume that snippet is for a bash shell?  Here is something similar (without the log file) in PowerShell:  `Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {@{($_.name)=(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- $_)}}`

Comment: yes, that was for bash (I used git bash to test it on windows)